# Laravel 7.x Passport Error: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I'm using laravel 7.x

I tried to install Passport to my project.

When i try to run "composer require laravel/passport", firstly i got that error;

*"PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)"*

After i changed php.ini file's memory limit, from *memory_limit = 128M* to *memory_limit = -1* i am getting this error;

*"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."*

I'm adding a picture that you can see all of the error;

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VriTe.jpg)

i tried to run "composer require laravel/passport --ignore-platform-reqs" command, and added "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.7.3" at the end of require array inside composer.json but these solutions did not work.

my composer.json file is like this;

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.152",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "doctrine/inflector": "1.1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "iyzico/iyzipay-php": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're requiring `"doctrine/inflector": "1.1.0",`, `laravel/passport` requires at least 1.4 or 2.0.

Comment: I'm new on coding so is there any way to update doctrine/inflector?

Comment: Just change the line in your composer.json from `"doctrine/inflector": "1.1.0",` to `"doctrine/inflector": "^1.4",` , the rest should be taken care of, this is needed by the `illuminate/support`, but since it's not directly in your composer.json, it should be auto installed as a dependency of passport. Then don't forget to run `composer update` command

Comment: I changed to `"doctrine/inflector": "^1.4"` but when i tried to run `composer update` command i got error again. you can see error [here](https://ibb.co/ZJqtdS9)

Comment: Please post the whole debug info from the composer.. It looks like you will either have to upgrade the Laravel version to > 7.10.x, for example 7.28.x or install older version of passport.

Comment: I downgrade to passport version from 10.0 to 9.3.2 and it worked.Thank you for your help too much!